# javascript caml query returning all date values

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I'm using a CAML query to get events between two specific dates from a calendar. However, when the query runs it is still returning all of the events with the list. It looks as if it is not applying the 'and' operator correctly.

My code is:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><GetListItems><Where><And>' + 
  '<Gt><FieldRef Name="EventDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">' +
  startDate + '</Value></Gt>' + 
  '<Lt><FieldRef Name="EventDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">' +
  endDate + '</Value></Lt></And></Where>' + '
  <ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Title" /><FieldRef Name="EventDate" /></ViewFields>' +
 '<QueryOptions /></GetListItems></View>');
```

startDate and endDate are converted to ISO8601 format, if I just do the greater part of the caml query then I return all list items after that date. It's just when adding in the less than part of the caml query I start getting errors. The caml works fine in U2U query builder.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've changed the query evaluators from <Gt> to <Geq> and <Lt> to <Let> and also removed the <View> tags and this seems to have done the trick.

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, please post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the query evaluators from  to  and  to  and also removed the  tags and this seems to have done the trick